# What is the Python equivalent to 'UnionAll' in SQL and how to use it?

Tags: python, sql, dataframe

I need to combine a dataframe with a list, in a way similar to UnionAll in SQL. This is an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([('A',10),('B',20),('C',30)], columns=['code','value'])
```

df1

```
code   value
 A       10
 B       20
 C       30
```

list_A = [100, 200, 300]

as the result, I need to get a dataframe as follow:

```
code   value   list_A
 A       10      100
 A       10      200
 A       10      300
 B       20      100
 B       20      200
 B       20      300
 C       30      100
 C       30      200
 C       30      300
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to achieve your desired result, but this only works if the number of rows in `df1` is equal to the length of `list_A`. (I think that is the only way your problem makes sense anyway).

First use [`pandas.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to "repeat" your DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = reduce(
    lambda a, b: pd.concat([a, b]),
    (df1 for i in range(len(list_A)))
)

df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then add the new column:

```
df2['list_A'] = list_A * len(list_A)
```

Output:

```
#  code  value  list_A
#0    A     10     100
#1    B     20     200
#2    C     30     300
#3    A     10     100
#4    B     20     200
#5    C     30     300
#6    A     10     100
#7    B     20     200
#8    C     30     300
```

If you're using python3, you will need to import `reduce()`:

```
from functools import reduce
```